# What is Async in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

If I am trying to write an app.post() function why do some examples use async and some just writes a regular function(req,res)? What does async do that is different from regular function?

Comment: allows you to use `await`. If your function doesn't use `await` anywhere, it doesn't need to be async.

Comment: Did you check this ? [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async (Asynchronous) function gives your code the ability to pause for any action. Let's see some examples:

```js
SamplePost = (data) => {
    let result;
    result = Request.Send("POST", data);
    console.log(result);
}
```

If you run the above function with an actual POST request It'll print `null` because by the time the result of the request will be fetched the console.log will finish executing.

```js
SamplePost = async (data) => {
    let result;
    result = await Request.Send("POST", data);
    console.log(result);
}
```

But in the above code it will print the actual result. Because this time the code will pause at the `async` and as long as it doesn't return any value (Not a Promise) it'll keep waiting and as soon as it'll get a return value it'll continue the code.

Sorry in advance for overcomplicating